# Blend mode to replace highest alpha?

Tags: android, alphablending, skia, xfermode

Is there a blend mode that does the following? Essentially take the highest alpha closest to opaque.

```
A = (Da > Sa) ? Da : Sa  
C = Sc
```

I'm more interested in the alpha behavior than the color behavior.